# Struggling to do a basic AJAX request in Laravel 5.3

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to do a very basic AJAX request in Laravel, and it keeps giving me a 500 Internal Server Error. I attempted to add in the appropriate headers, but still no luck. Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

My Route:

```
Route::get('/checkpin', 'EmployeeLoginController@checkPin');
```

My Controller:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class EmployeeLoginController extends Controller {
        public function __construct() {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }

        public function login(){
            $employees = DB::table('employees')->where([['clientID', '=', Auth::user()->userEmail]])->get();
            $adminEmployees = DB::table('employees')->where([['clientID', '=', Auth::user()->userEmail]]])->get();
            return view('auth/employee-login')->with(array('employees' => $employees, 'admins' => $adminEmployees));
        }

        public function checkPin($request) {

            if ($request->isMethod('post')){    
                return response()->json(['response' => 'This is post method']); 
            }

            return response()->json(['response' => 'This is get method']);
        }
    }
```

My AJAX:

```
$(".submit-key").click(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/checkpin",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

As previously mentioned, whenever I hit the button, I get an error in my console that says 500 (Internal Server Error).

Does anybody have any idea what it is that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the response in browser there will be some error

Comment: @lewis4u I'm not sure what you mean. Check it in the browser how?

Comment: I'm not at the computer now. So I can't send you a screenshot. But open the inspection view with F12 and go to Network tab and then click the button. There you will see that ajax call and when you click on it there will be some tabs and go through them you will find what is the error

Comment: Click the button that makes ajax call in browser I mean

Comment: And watch parallel what happens in Network tab

Comment: The error that the page produces says: "Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeLoginController::checkPin()". So - I guess the follow-up question is - how do I pass in an argument to a route that calls a method in a controller?

Comment: Yeah. You are not sending anything in your ajax...search for ajax submit form

Comment: Even if I pass data into the AJAX, it continues to give the same error. I feel like my route needs to be adjusted, but I am not sure how to adjust it, to pass in a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try, first try to remove / from the beginning of the route:

```
Route::get('checkpin', 'EmployeeLoginController@checkPin');
```

And add type casting to your function

```
public function checkPin(Request $request) { ...
```

Then it won't be treated as parameter.